Configure hostapd with sae_password and vlanid
According to the hostapd documentation, when you use WPA3, the hostapd AP can bind to a vlan interface based on the received passphrase.

an optional VLAN ID specification can be used to bind the station
to the specified VLAN whenever the specific SAE password entry is used.
[...]
#sae_password=example secret|vlanid=3|id=pw identifier

I have a minimal working hostapd configuration for WPA3 but it does not work if I try to bind to a vlan :
interface=wlan0
ssid2="Test-44"
country_code=<REDACTED>

# Advertises the country_code and the set of allowed
# channels and transmit power levels based on the regulatory limits.
ieee80211d=1

logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=0
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=1

driver=nl80211

ieee80211n=1
ieee80211ac=1

# Support for 802.11a(c|x)
hw_mode=g

# Required for 802.11n/802.11ac/802.11ax
# https://www.wi-fi.org/discover-wi-fi/wi-fi-certified-wmm-programs
wmm_enabled=1

# Enable WPA. Needed for WPA3
wpa=2

# Set of accepted key management algorithms (SAE = WPA3 / WPA-PSK = WPA2)
wpa_key_mgmt=SAE
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

# ieee80211w: Enable management frame protection (MFP)
ieee80211w=2

sae_password=password|vlanid=100

root@router ~# ip l
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: lan: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: vlan100@wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Hostapd seems to correctly see the VLAN interface :
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=4 ifname=wlan0 operstate=2 linkmode=0 ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x1002 ()
nl80211: Ignore interface down event since interface wlan0 is up
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=9 ifname=vlan100 operstate=2 linkmode=0 ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x1002 ()
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=4 ifname=wlan0 operstate=2 linkmode=0 ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=9 ifname=vlan100 operstate=3 linkmode=0 ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])

But when I try to connect to the hotspot with a device, hostapd refuses with this debug log:
SAE: Assign STA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx to VLAN ID 100
Invalid VLAN ID 100 in sae_password

Any ideas?
